# Get product name in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, desktop-application

I'm developing a WPF desktop application and want the application's product name to be displayed as the title of the MainWindow. I wanted to know if there is a way in xaml to display the product name as the title. I don't want vb.net or C# codes I just want an XAML code.

Comment: @Clemens Not sure how its done in C# but in VB.net it get the product name using "Text = My.Application.Info.ProductName"

Comment: Have you seen [Application.ProductName equivalent in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321150/application-productname-equivalent-in-wpf). You can't use that directly in XAML, however a single line of code in the Window's constructor won't hurt.

Comment: @Clemens Ya there doesn't seem to exist a ready-made code in xaml that can obtain the product name but I'm able to get the name using mm8's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and use the static `Application.ProductName` property:

```
<Window ...
       xmlns:winforms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
       Title="{x:Static winforms:Application.ProductName}">
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at line 3: The name "Application" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms".

Comment: It seems VS is unable to find the namespace "System.Windows.Forms"

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`?

Comment: Opps! I had missed adding the reference. Now I have added the reference and now its working. Thanks.